# How would I create a python program that puts the shell into a certain state?

Tags: python, linux, shell, command-line-interface, argparse

For example if I run setstate.py
to shell would go from
~/Desktop $
to
(customstate) ~/Desktop $

sort of like in anaconda when you activate an environment

for example something like:

```
import shellstate

shellstate.set_state("custom_state")
print('set state to custom state')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand the question, because the premise does not make sense. There is no such thing as "**the** shell". There can be as many (including zero) shells open as the system's resources permit, and ordinarily, none of them is in any way special above the others. Each has its own, independent state, and the one that started your Python process only communicates with Python via stdin/stdout/stderr.

Comment: "sort of like in anaconda when you activate an environment" This is possible because the activation script is using **shell script**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. That would be a security breach.

The shell is a process, your python program is another.

What you call "anaconda when you activate an environment" is something else: you don't run another process, you run command in the shell. By sourcing a shell script. (I don't know anaconda well, but something like `source activate environment`, which is a shell command, not a python program)

Any "state" (or any other internal change of your shell) has to be triggered by a shell command. It can't happen from a command of another process.

Comment: would that mean that it would be possible to use os.system() to do this

Comment: Thank you so much i managed to use a .bashrc file and then just use a bash script to run the source command and then i was able to run my custom python3 executable instead of running the python3 as in  the python langauge and it worked again thank you so much, have a nice day